# How do I completely uninstall uTorrent?

Tags: uninstall, utorrent

I needed to clear up some space on my hard drive, so I decided uTorrent wasn't of much use to me anymore. So I go to `Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features` to uninstall it. *Except...* **it's not there**.

Using the Task Manager trick (right-clicking on the process and selecting `Open file location`), I find that the program is installed in `C:\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent`. I deleted the folder, but I doubt that's the end of the program.

Is there a way to completely uninstall uTorrent? (e.g. using an `uninstall.exe`)

Comment: You just delete the program it doesn't use the registry

Comment: 'countless malware detections', 'non-operational cracks', and 'long download times' are products of your downloading habits and internet speed.

Comment: @scriptHero Follow [this](http://superuser.com/a/1028257/270195)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uTorrent itself doesn't create many things, so you can just delete it.

If you're not sure, you can search uTorrent in Explorer and your Registry, and delete things related to it. Be careful when deleting Registry entries, as deleting the wrong ones can damage your system.

Comment: The malware isn't from utorrent, the malware is from downloading pirated software, the infectins would have happened regardless of what BitTorrent client used.

Comment: @Ramhound Indeed. There _is_ a good reason to use older uTorrent versions though (less ads, better encryption, etc)