# MediaFire Desktop Client Discontinued?

Tags: windows, desktop

What happened to the `MediaFire Desktop client`? I had it installed until recently when I started having problems so I uninstalled it. Now I can no longer find a download for the newest version on their website but I found one [here](http://mediafire-desktop.en.softonic.com/download). If I try to install it, it tells me that I already have the newest version installed, though I don't have it anymore.

[image]

How do I fix this and has the client actually been discontinued?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Or follow my method for uninstalling the software manually http://superuser.com/a/1028257/270195

Comment: Yeah, softonic sucks but at least I found one working download link on there for the client. I'll see if the installation works again now after using CCleaner's registry cleaning functionality.

Edit: Nope but I will try doing it manually now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I fix this and has the client actually been discontinued?

The desktop client will be discontinued as from Jul 30 2016 and **will no longer work**.

Presumably because of this it is no longer available for download from their website.

See the MediaFire blog post below.

---

#### Shutting down MediaFire Desktop, new desktop app coming

> May 18, 2016
>
> At MediaFire, we endeavour to always provide the best possible
>   experience for our users, this requires an intense focus on building
>   and supporting the features that can provide the largest benefit to
>   our users. We also recognise that the currently vibrant ecosystem of
>   cloud syncing clients provides many alternative choices for customers
>   looking for that desktop syncing functionality.
>
> As such, we have chosen to discontinue development and support of
>   MediaFire Desktop so that we can focus on the development of a new and
>   improved Desktop app that will make storing and sharing your files
>   with MediaFire even easier.
>
> This discontinuation of MediaFire Desktop will be effective starting
>   on July 30th, 2016. Beyond that date, we will no longer be providing
>   support for MediaFire Desktop which will cease to function.
>
> All files that were synced will continue to be available to manage and
>   share through your account on MediaFire.com and MediaFire’s mobile
>   apps for Android, Blackberry, iPhone, and Windows Phone.
>
> In the meantime, we’re hard at work on further improvements to the
>   MediaFire features that our users have most demanded. We’ll keep you
>   posted on new developments as we get closer to launching!

Source [Shutting down MediaFire Desktop, new desktop app coming](http://blog.mediafire.com/2016/05/on-to-new-things/)