# vmware uninstall old partition

Tags: vmware-workstation

I installed Vmware Workstation on Windows 10 on a partition named X:

I decided to get rid of that partition in order to increase the capacity of the C: drive but forgotten to manually uninstall VMware. When I merged the partitions I tried to re-install VMware, the installer told me that there is an existing VMware product (perhaps some informations were installed on the C: drive without my permission) that must be uninstalled:

[image: vmware wizard setup]

But if I click on "uninstall" it gave me this error: "the MSI '' failed. Invalid drive X:\"

I searched in the [VMware troubleshooting site](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1308) and followed the instructions, but it didn't worked. Please, someone help me. I need a solution that allows me to completely remove the old installation of vmware.

Thanks for anyone who helps

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: @Dario Try this http://superuser.com/a/1028257/270195

Answer (score 0):

If you install a program on windows and tell it to install to a specific drive then the following will happen:

1. Some items will be installed to the path you choose *(e.g. X:\program files\vmware\workstation 10\"
2. Some items will be installed to other locations. (Usually to C: or the drive which hosts the OS).
3. Entries will be made in the registry.

If you just delete the whole drive X then files installed in point 1 are gone, but the registry still contains its information. The installer looks for those and sees an installed program. This is why it complains.

A registry cleaner might fix it (Make backups first!). If that does not work manually search the registry for entries related to the old installation.

NB1: My usually program for cleaning is cccleaner.
NB2: I do nto work for them, nor am I releated to ccleaner in any way.
NB3: Just because it works for me does not mean that it will work for you. Always makes backups before messing with the registry.
NB4: Many registry cleaners and 'optimisers' are a bad idea. Do not apply them without need (though in this case I think there is a need).
Disclaimer1: